# How can I use python get connection to MySQL via pubilic IP?

Tags: python, mysql

I am trying to use python to get a connection to MySQL,

It is python code is :

```
import MySQLdb

conn= MySQLdb.connect(
        host='public ip',
        port = 3306,
        user='root',
        passwd='123456',
        db ='test_schema',
        )
```

so it always give the errors:

```
 _mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'pubilic ip' (10060)")
```

Comment: 'public ip' is a string.. you should enter an actual IP address here. if MySQL is running locally, you can enter 'localhost'

Comment: Where are you hosting the db?

Comment: the db is on my laptop, I use the python send from my laptop also. the host i just call it as public IP.

Comment: use `'localhost'` as suggested by @AK47

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Building off AK47's answer

You need to first find the public facing ip address of your machine.
Go to google and search `What's my ip address` you should get a set of numbers `xx.xx.xxxx.xx` for example `12.42.111.2`

Then in your mysql you need to modify the `conf` file if linux, `ini` file if windows

`/etc/mysql/my.cnf Unix/OSX` systems. 
`C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\` Windows system

change `bind-address` to your ip address from google.

Then in AK47's answer replace `host='127.0.0.1'` to `host=<ip from google>`

Comment: Thanks for your answer thing is I can't install the mysql server When it finished installing the configure page didn't give me next option it freezes on the type and networking.

Comment: it's a text file... you can also just reinstall it again and configure

Comment: I tried that several times, I don't know how to upload the frozen windows pic. It seems not allow me to do the configuration.

Comment: It seems I don't have the bind-address option in my.ini is there another way to do ??

Comment: you can just add it in since it's just a normal text file

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I found the problem is my router can not get connected to the network.so weird.

Answer (score 0):

Update your connection parameters to have an actual IP address in the `'host'` field

```
import MySQLdb

conn= MySQLdb.connect(
        host='127.0.0.1',
        port = 3306,
        user='root',
        passwd='123456',
        db ='test_schema')
```

Comment: Thanks for your answers, the thing is I want to try whether MySQL can receive data from outside. The public IP of my python scripts is my lap top IP.

Comment: Your database host would need to be listening on port 3306 then, and host='public ip' would be the public IP of the machine you're hosting your database

Comment: So that means I need another machine to test the db?

Comment: If you database is running locally on your computer, you can attempt to connect over the network using your IP address, but it needs to be sent out into the network and then come back in, if you use localhost/127.0.0.1, your connection wont go out into the network, it will just go directly to the localhost

Comment: thanks for your reply, the local host and the local IP address both working for me. but when I try to use the external IP it gives me errors. so that I really lost I checked my router the port forwarding for external and internal both are 3306-3307.